North Carolina filial law
I live in Canada and have an elderly father who lives in North Carolina. Can NC’s filial law affect me since I live out of state? I am retired living on Social Security with my Canadian husband.

You should probably add you and your father's nationality.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Also, WTF is FILAL? UUOAIC - Unexplained Use of Acronyms is Confusing.

Does this refer to North Carolina's Filial Responsibility Law? This law requires children to support their parents and failure can result in criminal charges. If so, please revise the question.

You may need legal advice from an attorney.  This place isn't for free legal advice, but you might still get a useful answer regarding jurisdiction.  FYI:  https://ncestateplanningblog.com/are-you-legally-required-to-care-for-elderly-parents/

@DaleM : "filial" is not an acronym. It's a word that you can find in a dictionary.

@MichaelHardy at the time, it was spelled FILIAL

Are there any examples of North Carolina enforcing its Filial Piety law? This might not have been used, or not in many years.
